# netplan error line 1 column 8

Tags: server, 18.04

Hi I have a problem with ubuntu 18.04. I need edit this file

```
/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

But when I use `netplan apply` see error linie 0 kolumn 8 this is ":".

```
#
network: 
version: 2 
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp0s3: 
adresses: [192.168.16.186/24]
dhcp4: no
dhcp6: no
nameservers:
addresses: [192.168.16.190, 192.168.16.186]


$ sudo netplan apply
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 1 column 8: expected mapping
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

my file looks like

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp2so:
            addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
            dhcp4: no
    version: 2
```

**Replace `enp2so` with your network adapter name(enp0so3)** you could try that

Comment: this same linie 0 kolumn 8 :/

Comment: have you used indentation?

Comment: No I don't use indentation. This is truth is a new contribution but for me beter will be old.

Comment: I give Tab but now I have error 0 line 0 colum :/

Comment: [link] (<a href="https://www.fotosik.pl/zdjecie/eb52410568bf060c" </a>)[/link]

Comment: When I del space beetwin addresses:[192.168.16.186] I have error 4line 14 column mapping value are not allowed...

Comment: @PrzemysławKrawiec I looked at your fotosik.pl image. Your .yaml file is all wrong. You have to stop messing with the indentation, and putting things where they don't belong. Review my answer and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You **MUST** retain indentation.

Here is probably what your .yaml file should look like...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.16.186/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.16.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.16.190, 192.168.16.186]
```

Then, in `terminal`...

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply current configuration

`reboot` # reboot the system

**Note**: see https://netplan.io/examples for more examples